# Intuition behind the Law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

For a random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$, the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) says that the average of the results obtained from a large number of trials should be close to the expected value and tends to become closer to the expected value as more trials are performed, i.e.,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}=\bar{X},\tag{1}$$

where $\bar{X}$ is the expected value.

But the same doesn't hold for the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-n\bar{X}.\tag{2}$$

In fact, $(2)$ tends to increase in absolute value as $n$ increases.

I am finding it very surprising and hard to understand. Because I expected that if the average tends to expected value, then the sum should tend to $n\times$expected value.

Let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-n\bar{X}$, then

$$\frac{Y}{n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}-\bar{X}\tag{3}.$$

The way I try to convice myself is as follows: when $n\rightarrow\infty$, the LHS of $(3)$ tends to zero, thus $(1)$ will hold. But $(2)$ will not converge to zero, because the sum of the fluctuations around the expected value sum up and increase, thus forming divergent series.

Any help on obtaining a better intuition behind the differences between $(1)$ and $(2)$ is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it we are assuming $X_i$ are iid ($X_i \sim \mathbb{P}_X$) with mean $\mu_X$

To be a bit more precise on (1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_1^n X_i = \mu_X\;\;a.s.$$

So the sample mean converges to the mean almost surely (or "with probability 1")

Key here is that the the sample mean forces the variance to go to $0$.

In contrast for $Y_n := \sum_1^n X_i - n\mu_X$ we get an unbounded variance:

$$V[Y_n] = \sum_1^n V[X_i] \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \infty$$

While the mean stays at $0$:

$$E[X_i] = \sum_1^n \mu_X - n\mu_X = 0$$

So we have an increasingly variable process with *stationary* mean.

Therefore, the larger the value of $n$, the *less* likely we are to have $Y_n$ near $0$, so we cannot have $Y_n \to 0,w.p. 1$ (since if $X \not\xrightarrow{p} Y \implies X \not \xrightarrow{a.s.} Y$)

Comment: your explanation is to the point, thanks!

Comment: @Lee happy to help!